# C++11: Explicit instantiation declaration vs. explicit instantiation definition

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

What is the difference between the C++03's explicit template's instantiation **definition** and C++11's explicit template's instantiation **declaration** ?

What I mean is why the instantiation definition is not enough to prevent the compiler from generating implementation for other types ? What is wrong in the below example: imagine I split up the template declaration and definition into two separate files:

A.h

```
#pragma once

template<typename T>
class A
{
public:
    A(T t);

private:
    T _t;
};
```

A.cpp

```
#include "A.h"

template<typename T>
A<T>::A(T t) : _t(t) {}

template class A<int>; // explicit instantiation
```

main.cpp

```
#include "A.h"

int main()
{
    A<int> a(5); // fine, compiler generates header file,
                 // linker links with implementation from A.cpp file

    // A<float> b(3.14f); // linker error, as expected
}
```

Is there any compilation time overhead in example above? If I understand correctly, in such case, using explicit instantiation **definition** in a separate *.cpp file (along with template's implementation) I make the compiler to be unable to implicitly instantiate the template with any other types. As such, why there is a separate syntax for explicit instantiation declaration ?

How can explicit instantiation **declaration** speed up compilation time, if I had ALREADY hidden the implementation in A.cpp file using explicit instantiation **definition**, and prevented compiler from generating body for other types. Is the "explicit instantiation declaration" somehow related to "explicit instantiation definition", I mean should I use them both, or these are completely separate features (e.g. explicit instantiation declaration can be used only if explicit instantiation definition has not been used) ?

Am I thinking right, that the explicit instantiation definition is only to trigger error in case no other translation unit instantiates the template using given type?

Comment: a great talk on template basics: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XN319NYEOcE

Answer (score 37, accepted):

When you put an explicit instantiation definition in the file `A.cpp`, how is the compiler supposed to know it's there when compiling `main.cpp`? The answer is that it can't, so it would still instantiate the templates used in `main.cpp`, and in your case using the explicit instantiation definition is useless and doesn't help.

A declaration of an explicit instantiation says to the compiler "do not bother instantiating this template, I will do so myself, somewhere else in the program", and the definition is what fulfils that promise.

The explicit instantiation must be defined exactly once, in only one file, but it can be declared multiple times in different files. This is nothing unique to templates, in C and C++ the same rules apply to (non-inline) functions: you can declare them multiple times in different files (usually by putting the declaration in a header) and then you must define the function exactly once, in one file.

So to make your example work properly you should add a declaration in `A.h`:

```
extern template class A<int>; // explicit instantiation declaration
```

Comment: So in other words the "Explicit instantiation declaration" (as it is called [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template)) is a declaration that wherever that template is instantiated in this file the definition should be obtained from elsewhere?

Comment: @dshepherd, yes, exactly. (And note that it's also called an "explicit instantiation declaration" in my answer, because that's it's correct name!)

Comment: If I add another translation unit, say B.cpp, I only need to include "A.h" just like I did in main.cpp, to use A<int>. What is wrong with this? It's still unclear for me why do I need explicit template declaration, if the example works.

Comment: @MarcAndreson, it works, but the compiler will instantiate the templates again in every file, and the linker will throw away the duplicates. That wastes time. Using an explicit instantiation in `A.cpp` means the compiler only needs to generate the class once, but to take advantage of that the compiler **has to know the explicit instantiation exists** when compiling `B.cpp` and `main.cpp`, which is why you declare it. But if you don't understand the benefit then just don't use explicit instantiations, noone is forcing you to use them.

Comment: But how can the the compiler instantiate this template in B.cpp file, if the A.h header file contains only declaration, and actual implementation is hidden in A.cpp file ?

Comment: The compiler instantiates the class `A<int>` in `B.cpp` and emits an undefined reference to the function `A<int>::A(int)`. The linker then finds the definition at link-time. If you use an explicit instantiation definition in `A.h` then the compiler will not instantiate `A<int>` when compiling `B.cpp`

Comment: So the compiler just generates class's declaration A<int> right? Just as if I have included header file of class "A_int" into my translation unit? But I guess "extern template class A<int>" will do the same, so I see no advantage, but I wish I understood it :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58431/discussion-between-jonathan-wakely-and-marcandreson).

Comment: In other words, *explicit instantiation declaration* is just a way to optimize the compilation. Without it, the code will still compile, but it might generate a number of implicit instantiations of templates that are already explicitly instantiated somewhere else. The extra (implicit) instantiations will be removed by the linker later. I.e. the end result is the same with or without *explicit instantiation declaration*, but with it the compilation process is spared some unnecessary work.

Comment: @Birger, ask your own question. There's no way I can know why "it doesn't work" because that's far too vague, so doesn't belong in a comment on a different question. The declarations should be at namespace scope, and if they're needed in multiple files they should be in a header (just like the templates themselves). My answer already says it should be in a header.

Answer (score 0):

> An explicit instantiation declaration (an extern template) skips implicit instantiation step: the code that would otherwise cause an implicit instantiation instead uses the explicit instantiation definition provided elsewhere (resulting in link errors if no such instantiation exists). This can be used to reduce compilation times by explicitly declaring a template instantiation in all but one of the source files using it, and explicitly defining it in the remaining file.
>   [Source](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template)

Here a declaration in `main.cpp` or `A.h` would have prevented `main.cpp` from generating (at compile time) code based on what parts of the template are visible, namely an `A.h`-based `A<int>` specialization:

```
class A<int>
{
public:
    A(int t);
private:
    int _t;
};
```

However the `main.cpp` code does need to know that `A<int>::A(int)` exists which means it must perform some sort of instantiation in order to learn all `A<int>` members, which is exactly what an `A.h`-based `A<int>` instantiation would do.

So yeah not exactly obvious how it is useful here - though subject to per-compiler/platform profiling.