# Fixing warning "Wundefined-var-template"

Tags: c++11, compiler-warnings, clang++

Searching for duplicates currently gives:

- [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39420569/472610) which specifically treats the case of a Singleton implementation, and in which the answers avoids the warning altogether with a different implementation.
- [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47230290/472610) which answers itself without solving the issue.
- A [suggested duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/495021/472610) which explains how to implement template member functions (not relevant).
- Another [suggested duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229883/static-member-initialization-in-a-class-template) explaining how to define template static members (not relevant).

As far as I understand, none of these answers the question of **how to get rid of `Wundefined-var-template` with clang++ 3.8+ in a situation similar to the MCVE below?**

---

File `a.h`

```
#ifndef A_INCLUDED
#define A_INCLUDED

    template <class T>
    struct A
    {
        static const char *name;
    };

#endif
```

File `a.cpp`

```
#include "a.h"

template <> const char* A<double>::name = "Johnny";
template <> const char* A<float>::name = "Dude";
```

File `b.cpp`

```
#include <cstdio>
#include "a.h"

void say_it() {
    printf( "%s\n", A<double>::name );
}
```

Run from a terminal:

```
$ clang++ -c -o a.o -std=c++11 a.cpp
$ clang++ -c -o b.o -std=c++11 b.cpp a.o
clang: warning: a.o: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
b.cpp:5:32: warning: instantiation of variable 'A<double>::name' required here, but no definition is available [-Wundefined-var-template]
    printf( "%s\n", A<double>::name );
                               ^
./a.h:7:28: note: forward declaration of template entity is here
        static const char *name;
                           ^
b.cpp:5:32: note: add an explicit instantiation declaration to suppress this warning if 'A<double>::name' is explicitly instantiated in another translation unit
    printf( "%s\n", A<double>::name );
                               ^
1 warning generated.
```

[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/CbhjFw422iuDTDPT)

Comment: IIRC that's just `extern template <> const char* A<double>::name;` and so on in the header, as the warning suggests.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25056802/472610

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do as warning message explain, add (in a.h):

```
template <> const char* A<double>::name;
```

[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/XwMXxNmRRUWb23eU)

Comment: Will accept when SO lets me; it wasn't clear to me what "explicit instantiation declaration" meant, or where it should be inserted. See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25056802/472610).

Comment: Are you sure that's a declaration and not a definition?

Comment: @Quentin That's precisely what [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25056802/472610) is about. I'm hesitating to close my question as a duplicate..

Comment: This is a declaration. C++17 says in [17.7.3.13]: "An explicit specialization of a static data member of a template or an explicit specialization of a static data member template is a definition if the declaration includes an initializer; otherwise, it is a declaration."